# sudo with a USERID - reverting old behaviour

Tags: sudo, users

In my systems running Ubuntu 18.04 I can run a command (as root) like

```
 sudo -u \#2000 echo hi
```

And this works to run the command as UID 2000, **even though uid 2000 does not exist** in the passwd file.   When I try the same thing on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, I get an error

```
 sudo: unknown user: #2000
```

Does anyone know how I can get back the old behaviour?  I specifically WANT to be able to run a script with privileges of a user that is not in the password file (in this case to use wpcli will privileges associated with a website whose files belong to uid 2000)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the Ubuntu developers will not re-open security holes. If you can do that in a current 18.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, then please file a bug report so that hole can be closed, too.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for your comment - do you know a reference to the security hole you are referring to, or anything I can google to get a grip on the this?

Comment: Interesting. According to the `sudo` changelog for the 1.8.3 branch, this would have been fixed in 2004: https://github.com/perlun/sudo-1.8.3p1-patched/blob/master/ChangeLog (commit 27c5888c86eb).

Comment: @Jos I think that what you are talking about is only applicable where the -l flag is used (which makes sense as it -l requires a lookup of the users shell in the password database)

Comment: @user535733 I've managed to get a tiny bit further, and I'm not convinced your comment is correct - on current version of the man page for sudo in Ubuntu 22.04 it states under --user option ...When running commands as a UID, many shells require that the ‘#’ be escaped with a backslash (‘\’).  Some security policies may restrict UIDs to those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy allows UIDs that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is not set.  Other security policies may not support this." **so how to change the security policy?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [`sudoers(5)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sudoers.5.html), this behavior is controlled by `runas_allow_unknown_id` option now:

```
 runas_allow_unknown_id
                   If enabled, allow matching of runas user and group IDs that are not
                   present in the password or group databases.  In addition to explicitly
                   matching unknown user or group IDs in a Runas_List, this option also
                   allows the ALL alias to match unknown IDs.  This flag is off by default.

                   This setting is only supported by version 1.8.30 or higher.  Older
                   versions of sudo always allowed matching of unknown user and group IDs.
```

So you can add `Defaults runas_allow_unknown_id` to `/etc/sudoers` (use `visudo` to safely edit that file), and then `sudo` would allow you to specify arbitrary UIDs like in older versions (pre-20.04).

Note that restoring old behavior may not be safe since the setting was introduced in response to [CVE-2019-19232](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-19232) and [CVE-2019-19234](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-19234).

P.S. Also note that `sudo` cannot pick GID when the user specified by UID is not present (e.g. not listed in `/etc/passwd`), therefore it runs the command with the same primary and supplementary GIDs as the caller process has, which is not always a good idea:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# sudo -u \#2000 id
uid=2000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
#
```

I guess that using `sudo` in a way described might has other security complications too.

Comment: Thank you.  That appears to have done the trick.  Including the CVE's of concern was a nice touch as well,